# Universe has no foundation- Iyov

Tags: creation, job-iyov-book-of

What pasuk in Iyov says that the universe has no foundation? 
This connects to Brias HaOlam in perek aleph of bereshis.

Comment: You mean תולה ארץ על בלימה, Who hangs the Earth on nothing (Iyov 26:7)?

Comment: Raphael,  [welcome to Mi Yodeya](//judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887), and thanks for bringing your question here! Could you please [edit] in some details about why you suspect that such a posuk exists?

Answer (score 7):

[Job 26:7](https://he.m.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%92%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%94:%D7%90%D7%99%D7%95%D7%91_%D7%9B%D7%95_%D7%96):

> נוטה צפון על-תוהו;    **תולה ארץ, על-בלי-מה**.

[Trans.](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16428):

> He stretches out the north over chaos; **He suspends the earth on nothing**

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: Wow, such sticklers I'm bumping into here. I'm fairly certain that's what OP is looking for. Can OP decide if it answers his/her question?